# Plug and play login system?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, authentication, registration

Does anybody know of a plug-and-play login system that supports existing logins like Google and OpenID?
I am looking to implement something similar to that of Stack Overflows.
Thanks!

---

RPX is indeed what I was looking for. Are there any other systems like RPX that do a similar thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RPX](https://rpxnow.com/) is likely what you're looking for.

EDIT: For similar solutions, Google is your friend. ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) is a plug-and-play authentication system for Ruby on Rails.  Via it's plugin system, it supports Facebook Connect, OpenID, OAuth, and LDAP (among others).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about plug-and-play, but I started working with [openidenabled.com's PHP library](http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/) and it looks like it does the job pretty well with very minimal setup involved on the PHP application side.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at [Gigya](http://www.gigya.com/) along with RPX.